# ImportError: cannot import name 'warn' from 'bokeh.util.warnings'

Tags: python, bokeh, panel

I'm trying to use panel with jupyter in VS Code but I get this error.

Here is everything that I imported to my code:

- pandas
- warnings
- numpy
- panel
- panel.extension('tabulator')
- hvplot.pandas

Current bokeh version is 3.1.1. I've tried with bokeh 2.4.0 and 2.4.3 but it just got worse.

Code in Jupyter:

```
data_slider = pn.widgets.DateRangeSlider(
    name='Periodo',
    start=df_base['DATA'].min(),
    end=df_base['DATA'].max(),
    value=(df_base['DATA'].min(), df_base['DATA'].max()),
    step=2
)
data_slider
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py:974, in MimeBundleFormatter.__call__(self, obj, include, exclude)
    971     method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    973     if method is not None:
--> 974         return method(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    975     return None
    976 else:

File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\panel\viewable.py:623, in Viewable._repr_mimebundle_(self, include, exclude)
    620     loaded = hv.extension._loaded
    622 if config.comms in ('vscode', 'ipywidgets'):
--> 623     widget = ipywidget(self)
    624     if hasattr(widget, '_repr_mimebundle_'):
    625         return widget._repr_mimebundle_(include=include, exclude=exclude), {}

File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\panel\io\notebook.py:384, in ipywidget(obj, **kwargs)
    367 def ipywidget(obj: Any, **kwargs: Any):
    368     """
    369     Returns an ipywidget model which renders the Panel object.
    370 
   (...)
    382     Returns an ipywidget model which renders the Panel object.
    383     """
--> 384     from jupyter_bokeh.widgets import BokehModel
    386     from ..pane import panel
    387     model = panel(obj, **kwargs).get_root()

File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_bokeh\__init__.py:9
      5 from ._version import __version__
      7 HERE = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
----> 9 from .widgets import BokehModel
     10 with (HERE / "labextension" / "package.json").open() as fid:
     11     data = json.load(fid)

File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_bokeh\widgets.py:33
     31 from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LayoutDOM
     32 from bokeh.protocol import Protocol
---> 33 from bokeh.core.serialization import Deserializer, Serialized
     34 from bokeh.model import Model
     36 from ._version import __version__

File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\serialization.py:63
     47 from ..util.dataclasses import (
     48     Unspecified,
     49     dataclass,
     50     entries,
     51     is_dataclass,
     52 )
     53 from ..util.serialization import (
     54     array_encoding_disabled,
     55     convert_datetime_type,
   (...)
     61     transform_series,
     62 )
---> 63 from ..util.warnings import BokehUserWarning, warn
     64 from .types import ID
     66 if TYPE_CHECKING:

ImportError: cannot import name 'warn' from 'bokeh.util.warnings' (c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bokeh\util\warnings.py)
```

EDIT: New error without changing anything.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 4
      2 import warnings
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 import panel as pn
      5 pn.extension('tabulator')
      6 import hvplot.pandas

File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\panel\__init__.py:48
      1 """
      2 Panel is a high level app and dashboarding framework
      3 ====================================================
   (...)
     46 https://panel.holoviz.org/getting_started/index.html
     47 """
---> 48 from . import layout  # noqa
     49 from . import links  # noqa
     50 from . import pane  # noqa

File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\panel\layout\__init__.py:31
      1 """
      2 Layout
      3 ======
   (...)
     29 https://panel.holoviz.org/getting_started/index.html
     30 """
---> 31 from .accordion import Accordion  # noqa
     32 from .base import (  # noqa
     33     Column, ListLike, ListPanel, Panel, Row, WidgetBox,
     34 )
     35 from .card import Card  # noqa

File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\panel\layout\accordion.py:9
      5 import param
      7 from bokeh.models import Column as BkColumn, CustomJS
----> 9 from .base import NamedListPanel
     10 from .card import Card
     12 if TYPE_CHECKING:

File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\panel\layout\base.py:17
     13 import param
     15 from bokeh.models import Column as BkColumn, Row as BkRow
---> 17 from ..io.model import hold
     18 from ..io.state import state
     19 from ..reactive import Reactive

File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\panel\io\__init__.py:9
      7 from .cache import cache  # noqa
      8 from .callbacks import PeriodicCallback  # noqa
----> 9 from .document import init_doc, unlocked, with_lock  # noqa
     10 from .embed import embed_state  # noqa
     11 from .logging import panel_logger  # noqa

File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\panel\io\document.py:20
     17 from bokeh.document.document import Document
     18 from bokeh.document.events import DocumentChangedEvent, ModelChangedEvent
---> 20 from .model import monkeypatch_events
     21 from .state import curdoc_locked, state
     23 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

File c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\panel\io\model.py:20
     16 from bokeh.document.events import (
     17     ColumnDataChangedEvent, DocumentPatchedEvent, ModelChangedEvent,
     18 )
     19 from bokeh.model import DataModel
---> 20 from bokeh.models import Box, ColumnDataSource, Model
     21 from bokeh.protocol import Protocol
     22 from typing_extensions import Literal

ImportError: cannot import name 'Box' from 'bokeh.models' (c:\Users\acunha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bokeh\models\__init__.py)
```

Comment: You've deleted the part of the stack trace that actually shows what module/package the error is originating from. Please (always) post entire tracebacks.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I didn't notice the error was truncated.

Comment: `panel` only supports up to Python 3.10: https://panel.holoviz.org/getting_started/installation.html It's likely that Python 3.11 has some version issue with the `bokeh` library version it wants to use versus what is available. The first thing to always check when there's a version issue with modules, is if your Python version is supported.

Comment: It is unlikely that the Python 3.11 version is an issue. Most python codebases are forward-compatible with future Python versions by default. Bokeh has no issues with Python 3.11 even before we started officially testing with it. The `Box` class was removed from Bokeh 3.0 so whatever version of Panel you currently have installed must be expecting Bokeh 2.x at most.

Comment: As for the other, `warn` was *added* to `bokeh.util.warnings` in Bokeh 3.0 but the import causing the exception is coming from another Bokeh module. To be honest I think this indicates your install is corrupted in some way (e.g. files from multiple versions existing side by side, when they should not be). I'd encourage you to look into virtualenvs or conda environments, so you can quickly and safely blow away environments without manually mucking with your `site-pacakges`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was reinstalling the following packages with these specific versions:

`pip install panel==0.14.4, bokeh==2.4.3, jupyter-bokeh==2.0.4`

Hope this helps.